# Inscrutable lighting artifact in eevee

Tags: light, lighting, eevee-render-engine

I have this lighting artifact in render mode (only eevee though) that leaves a "square". Both meshes are manifold, everything is quads (no ngons, tris). The light source is an area light, but the same artifact shows from point light. Subsurface modifiers are the only modifiers that are present and even when applied the problem is still there. Here are screen shots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any ideas, is this only eevee stuff that I can ignore?

Comment: Scene (where you change engine) > Shadows > **Cube Size = 4096px, Cascade Size = 4096px**

Answer (score 1):

You can try moving the lights around a bit and increasing shadow resolution. You can also turn on screen space ambient occlusion to try to mask the error. Other than that, it's nothing you did wrong, just Eevee, as far as I know.